# Faster builds with arduino-cli

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32, arduino-cli

I have a script that uses arduino-cli to generate a compiled build of my sketch that has a dependency on arduinoWebSockets among other libraries.
Each build takes a lot of time, as it compiles all the library in the sketch every time I build the sketch, the sketch has a unique identifier that changes for each build, is there some way I can speed up the builds? I get that using precompiled versions of libraries is one way to go, but I am not sure how to get them or use them. Any help would be much appreciated as right now it takes about a minute or more to compiled my code

Comment: if the libraries are in Arduino 1.5 form (src folder and library.properties file), try to add `dot_a_linkage=true` into the library.properties file